# Copy "Filesystem on Target Machine" to bin/Debug and bin/Release

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, setup-project

*I did a lot of googling, but didn't find any answer for this problem so far...*

I defined the `File System on the Target Machine` for my program in Visual Studio 2010.
It includes all of the external Files (like XML's and batch files) which are needed to run the program. The files are stored in the `Program Files` folder.

The thing is now that if I try to debug my program, it says that it can't find the needed files in `MyTool/MyStartProject/bin/Debug`.

Is there any way to tell visual studio that it must copy these files to the Debug and Release folder to run the program?

I don't want to copy all files to the bin folder every time I want to run my program.

Thanks for any hint!

**EDIT:**

This is how my 'File System on Target Machine' looks like:

[image: File System on Target Machine]

I created it using the built-in editor and Drag&Drop of the files and folders I need.

Comment: What did you do to define the file system on the target machine?

Comment: sorry, did not read through your question, it is not a question related to setup project, you are asking how to copy to debug/release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the needed files to your project, and for each file, open `File Properties` pane, select "Copy always" in the [Copy to Output directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c6xyb66(v=vs.100).aspx) property.

[image: Copy to Output Directory]

Comment: you might not need "Copy always", but instead use "Copy if newer" and also make sure that you dont do this for code files!